# Schedule Python Script to Run Using Task Scheduler w/Windows7 -- Error (0x2)

Tags: python, cron, windows-task-scheduler

I have a Python script that manually runs without any issues. My Python code essentially writes a pandas data frame to a MSSQL server.

I am trying to setup Task Scheduler to automatically run my Python script at a certain time every day, but I always get the 0x2 error -- see screen shot below.

[image]
Below are the criteria I selected on the tabs in Task Scheduler:

General Tab: I have also run without checking "Run with highest privileges" ... same error result
[image]

Actions Tab

[image]

Conditions Tab
[image]

Comment: Error 2 is "file not found".  We can't see what exact ilename you specified, but remember that it has to be relative to your "Start in" directory.